# SQL Server: round decimal number and convert to int (within Select)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, int, rounding

I am using the following line within a Select which returns a number with decimals, 
e.g. 33.33333.

How can I round this within the Select and convert to integers so that I don't have decimals, e.g. in the above example it should return 33 ?

```
100 * AVG(CASE WHEN col2 = col3 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS matchPercent
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `ROUND` function to round the value to integer:

```
ROUND(INT, 100 * AVG(CASE WHEN col2 = col3 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END), 0) AS matchPercent
```

This will retain the type, e.g rounded `float` will stay `float`. If you also need to return `int` data type (or other integer data types), you need to also convert it:

```
CONVERT(INT, ROUND(INT, 100 * AVG(CASE WHEN col2 = col3 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END), 0)) AS matchPercent
```

Comment: Converting to `int` won't round the number, it will truncate it.

Comment: @Guffa, you're right, how did I miss it? +1 for you.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `round` function to round the number:

```
ROUND(100 * AVG(CASE WHEN col2 = col3 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END), 0) AS matchPercent
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to round the number first and then convert it to an integer, you also can add 0.5 to the number that you want to convert to an integer.

Comment: Makes it pretty easy.  Nice thought!

Answer (score 0):

Below statement rounds a decimal value to nearest integer

```
ROUND(decimalvalue,0)

ROUND(number, decimals, operation)
```

Example

```
ROUND(94.503,0)
```

Result: 95

Example

```
ROUND(94.403,0)
```

Result: 94